# Why does boost have different downloads for windows and linux?

Tags: boost, cross-platform, dependency-management

This might be a stupid question, but if boost is meant to be cross-platform, why does each platform need its own version?

If I want to package a (header-only) subset of boost as a dependency with my project, do I need to include both windows and linux versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line endings.

Windows IDEs typically prefer to edit all files in CR+LF (windows) line-ends.

All other platforms use LF (Unix) style line ends.

From [old documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/more/getting_started.html#.zip):

> #### .zip file
>
> The .zip format is widely supported by both free decoders and
>   commercial compress/archive utilities. If you don't already have a
>   .zip file decoder, download one from the Info-ZIP web site, which
>   supplies versions for many operating systems. Text file line endings
>   in the .zip file are as supplied by each library developer.  This
>   works fine for Windows, but not for Unix/Linux.  The .tar.gz and
>   .tar.bz2 files supply Unix/Linux friendly line endings.
>
> #### .tar.gz and .tar.bz2 files
>
> The .tar.gz format is widely supported on Unix/Linux platforms. Some
>   Windows compress/archive utilities can read the format as well. 
>   Because the gzip format compresses the archive as a single file rather
>   than compressing each file individually, the .tar.gz file is smaller
>   that the .zip file.
>
> The .tar.bz2 format is becoming widely available on Unix/Linux
>   platforms and is built into many tar utilities. This format differs
>   for the .tar.gz format in the compression used, which is considerably
>   better and therefore creates smaller files.
>
> Text file line endings in the .tar.gz and .tar.bz2 files have been
>   converted to newlines for ease of use on Unix/Linux platforms.